# Flex/Flash Builder is renaming my SWF after building

Tags: flex4, flexbuilder, flash-builder

It's only started doing this today, so I assumed it was something I've done, so I've opened a new workspace, created a new project, logged out, restarted, all of the usual suspects.

So the application is called ApplicationMain and the computer's name is Hobbes.

What happens is that after a build completes, I see the ApplicationMain.swf in the folder, and then a second later, it has been renamed to ApplicationMain (from Hobbes).swf
And every subsequent build, the files are renamed ApplicationMain (from Hobbes) #number.swf and the numbering continues up.

Cleaning does not get rid of these files. I've never come across this before, don't think it's an external program watching, but have no idea how to go about troubleshooting this further, I've run out of ideas.

Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)uninstall flash builder 4
2)remove C:\Users\%USER_NAME%.eclipse and C:\Users\%USER_NAME%\Adobe Flash Builder*
3)install Flash Builder 4.1
4)import your project and compile it.

Comment: Hmm, I'm running OS X and don't have the equivalent in my home directory, but cheers for replying :)

The problem went away, annoyingly, and just came back, more annoyingly. Will have a hunt for these folders.

Comment: hm, the idea is fully clean OS from all settings of IDe and install it again,check google for user folder of eclipse.